# Dropdownlist Selected Item is not showing correct item

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
// fill from database
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.connectionstring);
string readnamesquery = "select cwFullTitle from tbCowWorkers";

cn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(readnamesquery, cn);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

ddlUsers.DataSource = dt;
ddlUsers.DataValueField = "cwFullTitle";
ddlUsers.DataTextField = "cwFullTitle";
ddlUsers.DataBind();

cn.Close();

// insert selected value to database
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.connectionstring);
string registerQuery = "insert into Depot (dTdeliveryName) values (N'"+ddlUsers.SelectedValue.ToString()+"')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(registerQuery, cn);

cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

I fill a Dropdownlist from SQL Server, then send selected item to another table in SQL Server; but it send first item of Dropdownlist as selected item.

Selected item didn't change and returns default value.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is obvious, you are filling the dropdown list and then inserting the record, so it is bound to take the first item of the DropdownList.

I would suggest you separate the code of filling the dropdown list in another function and do the insertion only on selected_index change (ddl_SelectedIndexChanged) of DropDownList. In this ddl_SelectedIndexChanged function just check the selected value of the drop-down list and insert it to your target table (please remember to not invoke the call the function to load/Fill Dropdown List which you are currently doing in the shared code snippet).

SomeThing Like this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.connectionstring);
     string readnamesquery = "select cwFullTitle from tbCowWorkers";

     cn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(readnamesquery, cn);

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);

     ddlUsers.DataSource = dt;
     ddlUsers.DataValueField = "cwFullTitle";
     ddlUsers.DataTextField = "cwFullTitle";
     ddlUsers.DataBind();

     cn.Close();
    }
  }

  protected void ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // insert selected value to database
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.connectionstring);
    string registerQuery = "insert into Depot (dTdeliveryName) values 
    (N'"+ddlUsers.SelectedValue.ToString()+"')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(registerQuery, cn);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
  }
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     //Loading Dropdown by calling This.
     LoadDdl();
    }
  }
```

```
//Load Dropdown From Database.
protected void LoadDdl(){
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.connectionstring);
     string readnamesquery = "select cwFullTitle from tbCowWorkers";

     cn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(readnamesquery, cn);

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);

     ddlUsers.DataSource = dt;
     ddlUsers.DataValueField = "cwFullTitle";
     ddlUsers.DataTextField = "cwFullTitle";
     ddlUsers.DataBind();

     cn.Close();
}
```

```
//Inserting Item to another table by selected index change.
  protected void ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
//Checking If it's not the default value.
   if(ddlUser.SelectedIndex != -1){
  // insert selected value to database
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.connectionstring);
    string registerQuery = "insert into Depot (dTdeliveryName) values 
    (N'"+ddlUsers.SelectedValue.ToString()+"')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(registerQuery, cn);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    }
  }
```